# Declare typescript type with a generic key plus a predefined one

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My object has this structure (upstream, cannot be changed):

```
{
  "@metadata": {
    "authors": ["name1", "name2"],
    "locale": "en",
  },
  "key1": "foo",
  "key2": "bar",
  ...
}
```

All `keyN` must be strings, and the key itself could be arbitrary.  The optional `@metadata` block is well defined. How would I declare a structure like that in TypeScript?

I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. Thanks!

```js
type Messages = {
  readonly ['@metadata']?: any
  readonly [key: string]: string
};
```

Comment: How did it not seem to work? It looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partially do it with an intersection, meaning you can model existing data as follows:

```
const foo={
  "@metadata": {
    "authors": ["name1", "name2"],
    "locale": "en",
  },
  "key1": "foo",
  "key2": "bar",
} as unknown as Messages

type Messages = {
  [key: string]: string } & {
  '@metadata': any
}

let x = foo["@metadata"]
let y = foo.key1
```

However, as you see, I had to assert the type because TS will not let you create an object of this form.  This is a known limitation described [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#excluding-certain-properties-from-the-index-signature).

Comment: Thanks, I was having issues with using the data as it came from `import data from './messages.json';` -- and I guess I was hitting that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the generic variable as string like this

```
type Messages<k> = {
  readonly ['@metadata']?: any;
  readonly key: k;
};

const foo = () => {
  const data: Messages<string> = {
    key: 'stuff',
  };
};
```